# How to plot training loss and accuracy curves for a MLP model in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras, roc

I am modeling a neural network using Keras and I am trying to evaluate it with a graph of `acc` and `val_acc`. I have 3 errors in the following lines of code:

1. In `print(history.keys())` The error is `function' object has not attribute 'keys'`
2. In `y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)` The error is `name 'classifier' is not defined`
3. In `plt.plot(history.history['acc'])` The error is  `'History' object is not subscriptable`

I'm also trying to graph the ROC curve, how could I do it?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn import cross_validation
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras.utils import plot_model

dataset = pd.read_csv('Data_BP.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:11].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

def Model():
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 12, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['mse', 'acc'])
    return classifier

classifier = Model()
history = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.25, batch_size = 10, epochs = 5)

print('\n', history.history.keys())

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)

from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, classification_report, auc, roc_curve
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)


plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

What functions should be added?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `history` to `classifier` in the following lines (actually `History` object is the return value of `fit` method called on `Model` object) like this:

```py
classifier = Model()
history = classifier.fit(...)
```

Don't confuse the return value of `fit` method with your model. The `History` object, as its name suggests, only contains the history of training. However, your model is `classifier` and [it is the one that has methods](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) like `fit()`, `predict()`, `evaluate()`, `compile()`, etc.

Plus, the `History` object has an attribute called `history` which is a dictionary containing the values of loss and metrics during the training. Therefore you need to use `print(history.history.keys())` instead.

Now, if you would like to for example plot loss curve during training (i.e. loss at the end of each epoch) you can do it like this:

```py
loss_values = history.history['loss']
epochs = range(1, len(loss_values)+1)

plt.plot(epochs, loss_values, label='Training Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: @Diego The error 2 should not occur if you change your code as above. For the error 1, use `print(history.history.keys())`.

Comment: @Diego I have updated my answer. Are all the issues resolved now?

Comment: Update to `history = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.25, batch_size = 10, epochs = 5)` and I get the following error `'History' object has no attribute 'predict'` in `y_pred = history.predict (X_test)`

Comment: @Diego You should not use `history`. Your model is stored in `classifier` which is a [Sequential model](https://keras.io/models/sequential/). `history`, as its name suggests, only contains the history of training. Call `predict` or `fit` or `evaluate` on `classifier` instead. See my updated answer for the plots.

Comment: How could I implement the prediction function in the sequential model?

Comment: @Diego You don't need to implement it. [It is already implemented](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#predict). Just use `y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)`. That's it.

Comment: Thanks ... How could I implement a Confusion Matrix?

Comment: @Diego Again, you don't need to. You can use [the one already defined](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) in sklearn library. Please, do some research before asking.